# Dispatch incoming network messages to specific threads based on message IDs in iOS (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, swift2

I'm digging into iOS coding with Swift so I'm new.

My iOS app (actually a game) talks to a game server using a single socket connection and a custom JSON protocol. Messages are one-way (notifications) and request/reply (may be initiated on both sides). Request/Replies are tied together by using globally unique message ids. So this is quite different from simple HTTP/REST requests.

What might happen now (actually the problem which I need to solve) is for example:

- Server sends a request (asking for a specific action... e.g. players turn) (message id S01)
- App sends at the same time a request (for some different action... e.g. list buddies) (message id C01)

At the moment my iOS game uses a SocketConnection class which connects to the server and is able to send and receive (JSON) notifications/request/replies. However the part for response dispatching to the thread which initiated the request is missing.

I browsed the iOS documentation and loads of blogs/tutorials. All of them seem to cover GCD and how to use it for concurrency (loading off work into workers etc.)

What I need however is some kind of wait/notify like in Java. The game server is implemented in Java and does roughly the following when initiating a request for a client:

- take request and create a unique message id for it
- store it in a collection for later reference
- wait(timeout) on request object

In the background there's a dedicated (private) receiver thread which does receive all incoming messages:

while (!terminated) {

- wait for next message
- if message is a response look up the corresponding request by the message id
- put the response into the request
- notify() the request initiator on the request object

}

I though about separating connections into 3 or more so that interleaved request/response message would not occur at all - but I think this idea is not great due to a) handling multiple connections will make it much more difficult to keep the game stable and b) in the long-term it should be possible to play multiple game sessions in parallel inside the same iOS app instance.

At the moment I think that semaphores and sleep() could work which would resemble the pattern implemented on the server. But before trying to implement this I'd like to know if this is feasible. Semaphores seem to be quite fast but I would need millions of semaphores - one for every unique message id). <strike>And if using semaphores: how would I implement the wait() ? Using a busy loop with sleeps and polling the semaphore ?</strike> I think the wait() would simply use wait() on the semaphore.

Thanks in advance for any feedback or ideas.

Comment: Why bother with a custom wire protocol? Just use HTTP + remote notifications or web sockets and be done with it, so that you can focus more effort on the important and interesting aspects of making a game.

Comment: I'd love to focus more on the game itself :) However web sockets would require as well a custom protocol (pretty much what I have already in use) plus they/re more heavy-weight on the server-side (at least spring web sockets require a J2EE container) than what I have right now. Furthermore HTTP+REST plus some kind of "back channel" for notifications means 2 different message stacks which cries for problems I think. What kind of remote notifications did you think about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I need however is some kind of wait/notify like in Java.

This works poorly in iOS. It can generate too many blocked threads, which can deadlock the entire system. Instead, you need to think in terms of queues, not threads.

In general, the way this is handled in iOS is to include a completion handler or delegate along with the request. So your request would look something like:

```
conn.sendRequest(request, completion: {
   // thing to do when it completes
})
```

This does not block. `sendRequest` will put `completion` into a dictionary of request identifiers -> completion handlers. When the response comes back, you then look up the completion handler and execute it. For example:

```
if let handler = self.handlers[identifier] {
    handler(response)
} else {
    // We got a response we weren't expecting... This may be an error, or we might ignore.
}
```

For more details on why the async/await model works very poorly in iOS, see [Building Responsive and Efficient Apps with GCD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=718)
. See also the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), and particularly the section "Migrating Away from Threads."

Comment: I'm going to retune my brain cells and get a good understanding of GCD and queues :) Good to know that the semaphores idea would probably fail sooner or later. One thing which might be a good and a bad thing at the same time might be that for using queues the caller has to define the "calling context" so that it knows later on what the application state was at the time it sent the initial request. I presume the calling context is best passed inside the block (a block is what is placed in the queue right?) for reference...

Comment: @Alex correct. The block can hold state (it captures the variables in the scope it was created in), so the block itself has all the calling context you need in many cases. You can also create producer/consumer patterns using serial queues that can recreate much of what you're used to. Queues are pretty cheap (unlike threads), so don't be afraid to create queues to organize your work.